# Python find row that causes greatest variation in columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, classification, rank

I have a table where people rank cars according to which is their favorite ( number 1 as most favorite and so on). For the most part the top three cars are similar. However, I want to see which car rank sets them apart i.e. they rank which car lowest (they liked more) while others ranked that car higher (they liked less). Currently, the process is manual. I look at the standard deviation across the rows and from there look at the ones with the highest and then pick the one with the lowest number. I am not sure how to approach this in pandas or python. My table looks like this

| Car Make | Person 1 | Person 2 | Person 3 | Person 4 | Person 5 | Person 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daihatsu | 21 | 23 | 22 | 22 | 20 | 17 |
| Ford | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| (GWM) | 24 | 21 | 20 | 23 | 16 | 21 |
| Honda | 11 | 7 | 7 | 11 | 7 | 9 |
| Hyundai | 3 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| Isuzu | 20 | 12 | 15 | 17 | 9 | 11 |
| Kia | 7 | 5 | 12 | 12 | 10 | 14 |
| Mahindra | 16 | 18 | 23 | 19 | 21 | 19 |
| Mazda | 6 | 9 | 11 | 9 | 8 | 8 |
| Mercedes | 13 | 8 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 12 |
| Mini | 17 | 22 | 19 | 16 | 23 | 24 |
| Mitsubishi | 18 | 17 | 18 | 20 | 17 | 15 |
| Audi | 9 | 14 | 9 | 6 | 13 | 10 |
| Nissan | 5 | 6 | 4 | 7 | 4 | 5 |
| Opel | 12 | 10 | 14 | 14 | 12 | 6 |
| Peugeot | 14 | 19 | 16 | 15 | 22 | 18 |
| Renault | 10 | 13 | 8 | 8 | 11 | 13 |
| Smart | 24 | 23 | 25 | 23 | 25 | 24 |
| Suzuki | 15 | 11 | 13 | 13 | 19 | 16 |
| Tata | 22 | 20 | 21 | 21 | 15 | 23 |
| Toyota | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Volvo | 23 | 23 | 17 | 18 | 24 | 20 |
| BMW | 8 | 15 | 10 | 5 | 14 | 7 |
| VW | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Citroen | 19 | 16 | 24 | 23 | 18 | 22 |

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a new column with the standard deviations then look for the Car Make with the max and min value of std dev. I'm not entirely clear this is what you want but if not please clarify. Try

```
df['std']=df.loc[:, 'Person 1':'Person 6'].apply('std', axis = 1)
car_min = df['Car Make'][df['std'].idxmin()]
car_max = df['Car Make'][df['std'].idxmax()]

print(car_max, car_min)
```

which gives from your data:

```
Isuzu  Toyota
```